# Power BI report adding thousands separator in two of the columns

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

I am a complete newbie in PowerBI, so excuse me in advance if this is a stupid question. I have two columns which I would like to add thousands separator to their values.

[image]
I would like after the transformation for it to become 29,140

This is the panel I see:

[image]

Can someone please direct me to where I can make this change ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the column or measure and then click the comma under column tools on the ribbon.

[image]